# Django, 2.0.4 path is not work, how to fix?

Tags: python, django

Today for the first time installed the 2nd version of django and in shock from this shit, took and removed the normal routing using url I know that there is a re_path but this is not it!

> In general, everything was done according to the instructions as
>   django, but it does not work does not see any coincidences!

error

```
Using the URLconf defined in src.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    /
    ^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

main urs.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/', include("someapi.urls")),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

urls from my app

```
from django.contrib         import admin
from django.urls            import path
from .views                 import handle_verification, send_message
from django.conf.urls       import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    path('', handle_verification, name='handle_verification'),
    path('send/<str:recipient>/<str:txt>/', send_message, name='send_message'),
]
```

my views

```
import random
from django.core.paginator  import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts       import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http            import JsonResponse, Http404, HttpResponse
import requests
import json

def handle_verification(request):
    print("Handling Verification.")
    if request.args.get("hub.mode") == "subscribe" and request.args.get("hub.challenge"):
        if not request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == "my_voice_is_my_password_verify_me":
            return "Verification token mismatch", 403
        return request.args["hub.challenge"], 200
    context = {good:"I love HENTAI"}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)

def send_message(request, token, recipient, text):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        recipient = data.get("recipient")
        text = data.get("text")
        print(payload)
        r = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
        params={"access_token": token},
        data=json.dumps({
          "recipient": {"id": recipient},
          "message": {"text": text}
        }),
        headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
        if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
            print(r.text)
            return Http404
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Got')
```

Comment: try "path('/', include("<project-name>.someapi.urls")),"

Comment: @orenrevenge it cannot work man) i try

Comment: what page have you tried to get? (url)

Comment: if go through main urls it begin like this /

Comment: @joe513 path('', handle_verification, name='handle_verification'), from main urls it's just "/"

Comment: @DjangoMan has it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write `/` if you want to get page with no additional path. For example: `http://example.com/`

Instead of:

```
path('/', include("someapi.urls")),
```

Type:

```
path('', include("someapi.urls")),
```

Also, django requires app's name in case if you want to include app. Read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

> Remember! Standard path is `/` not

You type additional `/` and at the end you get `//`